# How to listen for an action that happens on another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Not sure if my "terms" are gonna be correct since I am new to this.

**Page A:**
Page that shows newly submitted questions.

**Page B:**
Page that a user can submit a new question on.

How do I make page A "listen" or "know" when a newly submitted question has been submitted on Page B in order for Page A to refresh the questions.

secondly: Do I have to get the server involved? Can I somehow listen for a client-side event?

**I can only use Angular JS and JQuery libraries.**

Comment: use something like socket.io and broadcast it.

Comment: I can't use other libraries made by other people.

Comment: You either need to use web sockets or ajax to communicate with server

Comment: refresh the B page at given times ? Ajax request ?

Comment: I don't get the downvotes? And this is for my project so i can't pay someone obviously... @JorelAmthor, when u say refresh at given times you mean just refresh every X minutes? that's not what i'm trying to do, or is that the way to you can do it client side?

Comment: @imZyzzBrah you already using jquery and angularjs

Comment: @Jacob 5. You are not allowed to use any third-party (or open source) libraries of any kind for the server
side code; except those required by Eclipse Mars, Tomcat and Java Servlets (the later should be
included in Eclipse Mars J2E distributions).
6. You are not allowed to use any third-party (or open source) libraries of any kind; especially
JavaScript libraries (except for the basic jQuery, Bootstrap and AngularJS libraries).

Answer (score -1):

**Page A:**

```
<a id="sendData">Send Data to Page B </a>

var url = http://localhost/yoursite/writeToFile.php
$('a#sendData').click(
               $.ajax({ url: url, type: "POST", data:{test:'test'} })
                .done(function() {
                      $(this).append(' sent!');
               });
)};
```

**Page B:**

```
<div>Listening to Page A </div>

window.setInterval(function(){
 listenToPage1();
}, 5000);

 function listenToPage1()
{
    var url = http://localhost/yoursite/readFromFile.php
    $.get(url, function(data) { $('div').html(data);   });
}
```

**writeToFile.php**

```
<?php
   $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
   fwrite($fp, $_POST);
   fclose($fp);
?>
```

**readFromFile.php**

```
<?php 
   readfile('data.txt');
?>
```

Assuming you're using PHP. Else you would should have to convert those scripts to your backend langugage.

**Yoursite structure**

```
www/
  /yousite
   readFromFile.php
   writeToFile.php
   page1.php
   page2.php
   data.txt
```